# MVC Displaying JSON Objects

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3

I am getting a list of objects from a database

```
public class TestCode
{
    /// <summary>
    /// ProductID
    /// </summary>
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public String CodeName { get; set; }
    public String ManName { get; set; }
    public String DOSName { get; set; }
}
```

My controller converts them to json using

```
 return Json(formattedCodes);
```

The controller is called by the following ajax

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#tags").autocomplete({
           source: function (request, response) {
               $.ajax(
               {
                   type: "POST",
                   url: '@Url.Action("GetAutoText3", "Code")',
                   dataType: "json",
                   data: { Code: $("#tags").val() },
                   success: function (data) {
                                               response($.map(data, function (c) {
                                                   alert(c.ManName);
                                                   return c
                                               }));
                   }
               })
           }
       })
   });
```

Previously I returned a json string and the above code worked fine. It still works fine but the input box isn't being populated with the autocomplete values, probably due to the fact that objects are now returned and the line "data: { Code: $("#tags").val() }," is probably no longer valid.

" alert(c.ManName);" returns the correct values so the objects are definitely there and correct.

I am looking for some 'model' way of allocating the data to the html, rather than concatenating a string together.

e.g the autocomplete will have the ManName and the CodeName values displayed but somehow I store the ID behind the scenes so as I can use this when the autocomplete item is selected.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: alerts are "fine" , but try and use firebug and step through,   put breakpoints in your url controller and see that it is getting called.  Glimpse is great,  Fiddler will be better in this situation.   Also use failure /error section   error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
        alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown);  etc.....

Comment: thanks for the good advice. I'll look into doing that. It doesn't really answer the question. The correct information is being returned. That is fine. It is how do I 'allocate json objects to the html' in the way (style) you would if using a model object. Not sure this is possible but looking for a recommended way to deal with json objects at the view end. thanks

Comment: That is why I used a comment section as opposed to the below box of "Your answer" as I had comments and suggestions and not a solid foothold / answer.  I will try and look at it later.